# sympy solving matrix equations as empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, sympy

trying to solve A @ B = 0 type of equation in here, A is a known matrix and B matrix contains unknowns, But code gives [] output, with subs(b,1) true solutions must be [0.618,1.0] and [-1.62,1.0] thanks.

```
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np
import math
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M = np.diag([2,2])  # ton
K = np.array([[600,-300],
              [-300,300]
              ])

M_inv = linalg.inv(M)
la, v = linalg.eig(M_inv @ K)


wn = np.sqrt(la)
wn.sort()

def matris(w):
    A = K - w**2*M
    return A

matris_1 = matris(wn[0])
matris_2 = matris(wn[1])

a, b, c, d, e, f = symbols('a,b,c,d,e,f', commutative=False)

fi_matris = Matrix([a, b])


def mod(matris_n):
    eq1 = matris_n @ fi_matris
    eq2 = eq1.subs(b,1)
    eq3 = Eq(eq2,0)
    solv1 = solve([eq3],(fi_matris))
    return solv1


mod_1 = mod(matris_1)
mod_2 = mod(matris_2)
```

after putting a zeros vector my equation to be solved is:

```
Eq(Matrix([
[485.410196624968*a - 300.0],
[185.410196624968 - 300.0*a]]), Matrix([
[0],
[0]]))
```

so a must be 0.618 and b is already set as 1.0
but gives []

btw i edited one of the functions to get that:

```
zeros_matrice = zeros(2,1)

def mod(matris_n):
    eq1 = matris_n @ fi_matris
    eq2 = eq1.subs(b,1)
    eq3 = Eq(eq2,zeros_matrice)
    solv1 = solve(eq3)
    return solv1
```

to be more precise eq above is eq3 in this case

i again edited the function as just to solve one row:

```
def mod(matris_n):
    eq1 = matris_n[:1] @ fi_matris
    eq2 = eq1.subs(b,1)
    eq3 = Eq(eq2,0)
    solv1 = solve(eq3)
    return solv1,eq3


mod_1 = mod(matris_1)
mod_2 = mod(matris_2)
```

in this case output is `([], False)`

Comment: Your `eq2` is a `Matrix` so `Eq(eq2, 0)` give False (a matrix is never equal to the number zero). Leaving that aside your equations (after substituting `b=1`) are overdetermined and inconsistent so you can only expect the empty solution. Lastly  I don't know what you think it means but don't set `commutative=False` if the symbols represent real numbers.

Comment: this is a classic dynamics solution, eq2 is a set of equations which equal to the 0 seperately, and b should be determined as 1 since i am trying to find solutions referring to the b being 1. But that is out of the topic. How do i find the solutions then ?

Comment: If you look at `eq2` you'll see that there are no solutions so there must be something else wrong. The only solutions to `eq1` are `a = b = 0`.

Comment: i edited the post please check, i think i made a mistake before while describing the issue

Comment: The two equations for `a` do not have exactly the same solution for `a` because of rounding errors in the numbers. That means that together the equations have no solution. Just solve one of the equations for `a` and you will get an approximate solution.

Comment: nothing changed. output is still ([], False) i really didn't understand the issue. by the way column index will be change for other system solutions thus i can't do any manuel dividing operation.